Do informal arguments carry rational weight only if they can be formalized into a deductive, inductive, or abductive argument?
Suppose someone writes an essay in natural language, structured in paragraphs, to argue for a thesis. If this essay cannot be formalized into one or more formal arguments—each adhering to the structure of a deductive, inductive, or abductive argument—can we justly label it as "word salad" that lacks any rational weight whatsoever?
In other words, should I only regard a sequence of words put together seriously if they can be mapped to a formal deductive, inductive, or abductive argument?

There is no "formal structure" to inductive or abductive arguments, they are in informal. And to the extent that they have structure it is loose enough to fit anything with premises and conclusions into it. One can claim that their conclusion is the "best explanation" of the premises, and people can have fun arguing whether it does 'really' explain or does so in the 'best' way. On fine structure of informal arguments see Toulmin's model.

Hint: word symbol as meaning is use which is subtly different from 'mention'...


Do informal arguments carry rational weight only if they can be formalized into a deductive, inductive, or abductive argument? Should I only regard a sequence of words put together seriously if they can be mapped to a formal deductive, inductive, or abductive argument?

A key issue regarding "formalization" is what it means. I think that is a whole topic in its own right. I do not know the answer, but here are some resources towards that end:

Formal Epistemology
This article does not analyze what is even meant by the word "formal", but it does give a tour of various systems that attempt to "formalize" reasoning and knowledge.

Formalism in the Philosophy of Mathematics

Logicism

Logic translation
The "sources" of section of this article includes many resources relating to the concept of "formalization" and "formality".

Formalism

All of the following are resources in which people try to analyze what "formal systems" or "logical rules" actually are:
Kripke's "Wittgenstein on Rules and Private Language"
Martin-Löf's "On the Meanings of the Logical Constants and the Justifications of the Logical Laws"
Girard's "Locus Solum"
Rav's "Why Do We Prove Theorems?"
Chaitin's "The Limits of Reason"
Chaitin's "The Limits of Mathematics"
Azzouni's "Why Do Informal Proofs Conform to Formal Norms?"
Lakatos's "Proofs and Refutations"
MacFarlane's "What does it mean to say that logic is formal?"
Quine's "Philosophy of Logic"
Marginally related:
The work of Soloman Feferman.
The Prehistory of Mathematical Structuralism.

On a separate note, here is an interesting blog post about how the logical concepts of deduction, induction, and abduction appear to correspond to certain simple diagrams in category theory.

Informal arguments are useful for exploring concept space, identifying our preferences and biases and preconceptions, and deciding what needs to be resolved to make them convincing.
But eventually it needs to become something more rigorous and more formal, to show that it is self-consistent and to show how it interacts with other theories and facts, or it remains a pretty fiction.
There's nothing wrong with fiction, and it can present a concept, but it doesn't do a lot to prove that the concept works in the real world. Cloud castles are fun, but you can't live in one.
